# Undefined reference to Magick::Image ::Image() in eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using Eclipse CDT on windows 7 64 bit and trying to work on Image Class using Image Magick but I am getting the below error-

```
#pragma warning(once: 4459) /* 'identifier' : declaration of 'foo' hides    global declaration */
g++ "-LC:\\Development\\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\\lib" "-     LC:\\Development\\opencv\\MINGW\\x86\\bin" -o testOpencv.exe "src\\testOpencv.o"    -llibopencv_features2d2410 -lCORE_RL_Magick++_ -lCORE_RL_MagickCore_ -   lCORE_RL_MagickWand_ -llibopencv_objdetect2410 -llibopencv_contrib2410 -  llibopencv_core2410 -llibopencv_flann2410 -llibopencv_gpu2410 -  llibopencv_highgui2410 -llibopencv_imgproc2410 -llibopencv_ml2410 -  llibopencv_legacy2410 -llibopencv_nonfree2410 -llibopencv_objdetect2410 -  llibopencv_ocl2410 -llibopencv_photo2410 -llibopencv_stitching2410 -  llibopencv_superres2410 -llibopencv_video2410 -llibopencv_videostab2410 - lopencv_ffmpeg2410 -llibopencv_ml2410 
src\testOpencv.o: In function `main':
C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:14: undefined  reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'
C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:15: undefined  reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::string const&)'
C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::display()'
C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

14:28:39 Build Finished (took 847ms)
```

I have added includes file to compiler and Library files in the linker in Eclipse. The library file in Image magick installed folder look strange to me, as they are not '.dll' files. Please let me know if I am right and how do i rectify this.

[image: lib files]

Comment: The `g++` command argument show that the library paths have been added to your project, but doesn't list any include header paths. Double check "Properties" > "C/C++ General" > "Paths and Symbols" > "Includes".

Comment: @emcconville :same error after ur suggested changes **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project testOpencv ****Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\\Development\\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\\lib" "-LC:\\Development\\opencv\\MINGW\\x86\\bin" -o testOpencv.exe "src\\testOpencv.o" -lCORE_RL_Magick++_ -lCORE_RL_MagickCore_ -lCORE_RL_MagickWand_
src\testOpencv.o: In function `main': C:\Development\Workspace\testOpencv\Debug/../src/testOpencv.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Build Finished (took 384ms)

Comment: is Magick++ better or opencv does all the job

Comment: @emcconville: Hi, so i had left using Imagemagick but then i have to use it now. And I am still getting the same error inspite of having included header files and library files of Compiler includes and Mingw C++ Linker respectively. Can you please help.

Comment: There's not much more I can help with. The `g++` command has the `-L` flag for path to libraries, and `-l` to link to library, but it's missing the `-I` option to set the path of the headers (which is what the error message states). Double check [the docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm) or manually build in CLI.